# 'const [a, b] = [1,2,3,4] '. What is the value of b in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

What is the value of b in the following code?

```
[a, b]  =  [1,2,3,4]
```

Is it any different from

```
[a,, b]  =  [1,2,3,4]
```

?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: The first one sets `b = 2`, the second sets `b = 3`